# Lambda in Java - Could not analyze lambda code

Tags: java, jpa, lambda

I’ve got an application with Hibernate (JPA) which I am using in combination with Jinq. I’ve got a table which lists entities and I want the user to be able to filter it. In the table there are persons listed.

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String surName;
    @Id
    private int id;
    public Person() {
    }
    public Person(final String pFirstName, final String pSurName, final int pID) {
        firstName = pFirstName;
        surName = pSurName;
        id = pID;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(final int pID) {
        id = pID;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(final String pFirstName) {
        return firstName = pFirstName;
    }
    public String getSurName() {
        return surName;
    }
    public void setSurName(final String pSurName) {
        surName = pSurName;
    }
}
```

I am using JavaFX for this, but this shouldn’t matter. First thing I tried was to filter the persons by their surname. For filtering, I used Jinq in combination with lambda. My filtering code looks like this:

```
private List<Person> getFilteredPersons(final String pSurName){
    JPAJinqStream<Person> stream = streamProvider.streamAll(Person.class);
    stream.where(person -> person.getSurName().contains(pSurName));
    List<Person> filteredList = stream.toList();
    stream.close();
    return filteredList;
}
```

So the object I am operating on is a normal String. I don’t think that my Person class has anything to do with that. My first thought was, that you can’t use the method `boolean contains(...)` in lambda because when the error showed up, it said:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not analyze lambda code
```

So my question is, is it somehow possible to use the contains-method of a String in lambdacode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with JPA or lambdas, but everything to do with jinq: it simply doesn't support translating `String.contains()` to a database query. See http://www.jinq.org/docs/queries.html#N65890 for what is supported.

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me :) have you any idea how i could realize it then but still use jinq?